# Nest while loop inside do while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I am new to Java and can't seem to find an answer to my question.
I am not sure if I nest loops properly.
The "while loop" inside the "do while" has to be executed only when person doesn't input "Yes" or "No" to the following question:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you have more grades to input? Please type 'Yes' or 'No'.");
```

But it turns out that if I input "Yes" or "No" the loop is still being executed.
If anybody could point what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it! "

```
  String input;
  int grade;

  do {
     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the midterm grades, please");
     grade = Integer.parseInt(input);

     if ( grade < 0 || grade > 100 ) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You have entered an invalid grade. The grade should be a number between 0 and 100. Enter the midterm grades, please.");
        grade = Integer.parseInt(input);
     }

     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you have more grades to input? Please type 'Yes' or 'No'.");

     while ( (!input.equals("Yes")) || (!input.equals("No")) ) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You should type 'Yes' if you want to input more grades or 'No' if you are done with inputing grades. Do you have more grades to input? Please type 'Yes' or 'No'.");

        if ( (input.equals("Yes")) || (input.equals("No")) ) {
           break;
        } else {
           continue;
        }
     }

  } while ( input.equals("Yes") );
```

Comment: (!input.equals("Yes")) && (!input.equals("No"))

Comment: Do you know what the De Morgan laws are? Your boolean condition is wrong. It will always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this:

```
while ( (!input.equals("Yes")) || (!input.equals("No")) ) {
```

Should be changed to `&&` like this:

```
while ( (!input.equals("Yes")) && (!input.equals("No")) ) {
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! Now It works exactly the way it should work!

Comment: Hey Daniel! I clicked on the checkmark. Unfortunately can't up vote your answer because I don't have enough reputation..

Answer (score 0):

You condition is wrong

```
 ( (!input.equals("Yes")) || (!input.equals("No")) )
```

When the input is "Yes", this evaluates to:

```
  ! true || ! false
```

which true, so the loop continues!

What you want is probably

```
while  ( (! input.equals("Yes")) && (! input.equals("No")) )
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the logical explanation! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to `&&` from `||`, ie. you should iterate if the input is different of "Yes" **and** different of "No"

You could rewrite your code as:

```
while (!input.equals("Yes") && !input.equals("No") ) {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You should type 'Yes' if you want to input more grades or 'No' if you are done with inputing grades. Do you have more grades to input? Please type 'Yes' or 'No'.");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String input = null;
  int grade = 0;  // local variables don't initlized by default value in function, only class fields
  int counter = 0;

  do {
       counter++;
       do{
           grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the midterm grades grade for " + counter + " student must be between 0-100 : , please"));
       }while(grade < 0 || grade > 100);   // promot user again if it enters data in wrong range till , he/she don't input correct value
       input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("If you want to Enter more grades then type 'Y' or 'Yes' .. ");

  } while ( (input.toLowerCase()).equals("yes") || (input.toLowerCase()).equals("y"));   // lower case because some users will type like "YEs" or something, can also use EqualsIgnoreCase function
```

don't know why you wrote too much lines :) , thanks :) ,, comment if any error i did not check and did not write program in java for last 2 years :p ,  and also added a facility like,  you promot will bel ike,  Enter grande for student 1,2..n etc, you can also remove that if you don't want :)

Comment: In your solution you checked the value of grade once, what if after entering wrong value once user entered it again , in your program it will accepted but in my code it will not, same with yes or no values also , :)

Comment: Actually my "Yes" and "No" in the if statement are fine because if I enter anything else but "Yes" or "No" it will go to "else" condition which would lead to continuing the loop. Hope its not too confusing :)

Comment: ok , but number of lines matters :p ! ,, you took 19 lines to write that buggy code, and i took 10 lines with 1 more feature ( that counter ) and removed that bug also, :) ,,  You used 2 if and i removed both :) , thanks

Comment: Totally agree on that! Thank you for helping out. I am a student so learning on mistakes